# Chart Js Annotation plugin doesn't show but no error

Tags: charts, annotations, chart.js

tried to copy other solutions but doesn't work. Chart shows but without annotation lines. Showing my code below. Really appreciate your attention
Integrated on base.html

```
<script src="path/to/chartjs/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/chartjs-plugin-annotation/dist/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>
```

On another page after extending base.html:

```
<script>

  // jquery function
  $(document).ready(function(){
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

    const labels = [{% for item in query_set%}'{{item.analysis_date}}',{% endfor %}];

    const data = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
      //Если добавить еще один - будет сдвоенный график
        {
          label: '{{analysis_info.a_name}} - {{analysis_info.a_measur}}',
          data: [{% for item in query_set%}'{{item.analysis_data}}',{% endfor %}],
          borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
          borderWidth: 4,
          
        },
      ]
    };

    const options = {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            min: 0
          }
        }]
      },
      animation: {
            duration: 1500,
        },
      plugins: {
        autocolors: false,
        annotation: {
          annotations: {
            box1: {
              // Indicates the type of annotation
              type: 'line',
              yMin: 10,
              yMax: 10,
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.25)'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    const config = {
      type: 'line',
      data,
      options,
      };

    const chart = new Chart(ctx, config);

  });
</script>
{% endblock scripts %}
```

But no reaction

I'm sure that solution is easy but i got stucked

Comment: I have tested your code and it's working. See codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/OJEZOrK Can you share the versions you are using?

Comment: i'm new to all this stuff but this code is written in html file and i'm using latest version of django framework

Comment: Shall I create a js file?

Comment: Can you share the chartjs and chart-plugin-annotation versions you are using?

Comment: imported via source
libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js
libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you repeorted in the comment, "imported via source libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/2.1.0", you are using 2 not compatible versions.

See Redame of plugin repo: https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation#readme

```
An annotation plugin for Chart.js >= 3.7.0

For Chart.js 3.0.0 to 3.6.2 support, use version 1.4.0 of this plugin For Chart.js 2.4.0 to 2.9.x support, use version 0.5.7 of this plugin
```

Comment: yeah, ty buddy, simply need to read first page of documentation .. :d